# Prevent Ultrabay HDD from ejecting on sleep

Tags: thinkpad

I have a lenovo T430s thinkpad with a small SSD primary drive and 500gb ultrabay drive. When I put the computer to sleep and then return, I get the message titled "problem ejecting < drive name >" "Windows can't stop your 'Generic volume' device because a program is still using it."

This pop up is very annoying every time every time I use the computer. I don't want to disable write caching [D:>Hardware>[drive]>policies>quick removal] because I want best performance and never remove the drive. Any ways to avoid this pop up?

Comment: same thing here! It's just annoying when the OS cannot eject the disk. But it's very terrible when it does. Because I have to reboot the system to get it back (Just ejecting and reinserting the ultrabay does not remount it)